How to stop the Tevo Tornado filament from oozing during the auto bed leveling sequence?
Based on the following Start G-code, I want the print bed to heat up to the material_bed_temperature first then do the rest of the G-code. However, it always heats up the extruder first to the material_print_temperature then does the rest of Start G-code. I feel like there's something in the Tevo Tornado firmware that executes the unwanted material_print_temperature command first then do the Start G-code, but I am unsure what specific section of the firmware to look for to fix this problem.


Please don't post text as an image; see Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?.
